# How to stop print repetition in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have been working on a code that involves using keywords from a list. The keywords when searched and matched from a string in a paragraph, the code prints out the string with the keyword. What I cant find out is a solution to print out the string without getting it repeated.
This is the code

```
import re
from random import randint

def foo():
    List1 = ['Risk','ocp','cancer','menarche','estrogen','nulliparity',]
    txt = " Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized. Factors associated with an increased exposure to estrogen have also been elucidated including early menarche, late menopause, later age at first pregnancy, or nulliparity."
    words = txt
    matches = []
    sentences = re.split(r'\.', txt)

    k = iter(List1)
    while True:
        try:
            keyword1 = next(k)
        except StopIteration:
            break    
        pattern = keyword1 
        re.compile(pattern)

        for sentence in sentences:
            if re.search(pattern, sentence):
                matches.append(sentence)           

                for match in matches:
                    print("Sentence matching the word (" + keyword1 + "):")##just to checkfor keyword matching
                    print (match)
        break

foo()
```

What i keep getting is seen here despite using 'break'. Can this be done better.

```
>> Sentence matching the word ("Risk"): " Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized. 
>> Sentence matching the word ("Risk"): " Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized.
>> Sentence matching the word ("Risk"): " Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized.
```

Sometimes i get a keyword used but the sentence is wrong

```
>> Sentence matching the word ("ocp"): " Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is a bit convoluted without a good reason. It's hard to describe what exactly is wrong (reusing variables not in the way you expect basically). Additionally the whole `while` loop can be a `for` and the `re.compile()` doesn't really do anything unless you use the result.

Potential rewrite:

```
sentences = re.split(r'\.', txt)

for pattern in List1:
    for sentence in sentences:
        if pattern in sentence:
            print("Sentence matching the word (" + pattern + "):")
            print(sentence)

            # uncomment break if you want only the first matching sentence
            # break
```